# When a ring is integral over a particular subring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, group-actions

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735796/any-ring-is-integral-over-the-subring-of-invariants-under-a-finite-group-action) asks for a help in proving the following exercise:

> If $G$ is a finite group that acts on ring $A$, and $A^G$ is the subring consisting of elements of $A$ which are invariant under all $g\in G$, then $A$ is integral over $A^G$. (Atiyah and Macdonald, Chapter 5, Exercise 12).

I am wondering **when** the following claim may hold:

> If $G$ is a finite group that acts on ring $A$, and $A^G$ is the subring consisting of elements of $A$ which are **fixed** under all $g\in G$, $A^G=\{a \in A|\forall g \in G, g(a)=a\}$, then $A$ is integral over $A^G$.

It seems that there are counter-examples to my above claim, hence I ask for an additional condition which will guarantee that it is true.

(What I had in mind: $A=k[x,y]$, $G=\{1,\alpha\}$, where $\alpha: (x,y) \mapsto (y,x)$. Then $A^G$ consists of the symmetric elements with respect to $\alpha$. I do not know if $A^G \subset A$ is integral or not).

Thank you very much for any help!

**Edit:** After reading the comments, I added to this question my exact definition of "fixed":  $A^G=\{a \in A|\forall g \in G, g(a)=a\}$.

Comment: What is the difference between fixed and invariant?

Comment: If I am not wrong: If $B \subseteq A$, then (1) $B$ is invariant under $G$ if $G(B) \subseteq B$. (2) $B$ is fixed under $G$ if $G(b)=b$ for every $b \in B$. Perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: But note the first statement you give doesn't say $A^G$ is invariant; it says each element of $A^G$ is invariant. In fact it is the same as your second statement.

Comment: Your definition $(1)$ doesn't make sense in this context. $G$ acts on $A$, so trivially $G(A) \subseteq A$, but we don't want $A^{G} = A$. Plus, it says that $A^{G}$ is the subring consisting of *elements* of $A$ which are invariant under all $g \in G$, which means that to be $G$-invariant in this context is a property of an element of $A$, not a subset of $A$.

Comment: For $A=k[x,y]$, $G=\{1,\alpha\}$: In my definition (1) $A^G=A$, while in my definition (2) $A^G \subsetneq A$, $A^G$ is the subring of symmetric elements w.r.t. $\alpha$. (But perhaps I am missing something?)

Comment: @AlexWertheim, so I misunderstood the quoted question, but what about my question? (I meant something similar to field theory).

Comment: To reiterate, this is independent of your particular example. You will *always* have $A^{G} = A$ as you have defined it, which renders any questions about $A^{G}$ uninteresting, including those of integrality. I think I've said all I can say about this, but just to say it one more time, your first block of text defines $A^{G}$ element-wise, while you are trying to define things subsetwise. I don't see how these could be coherent. Moreover, if you really want to understand your particular example, you can see exactly how $A$ is integral over $A^{G}$ (as I am defining it) via the linked question

Comment: @user237522 the correct interpretation of the first statement is the same as your interpretation of the second statement. In other words, your question is the same as the one you linked to.

Comment: More accurately, in (2) I meant: $A^G=\{a \in A | \forall g \in G, g(a)=a \}$. (In this definition, the skew-symmetric elements w.r.t. $\alpha$ do not belong to $A^G$). I really apologize for not being clear (your comments are not in vain; it is good, at least for me, to have them).

Comment: As stewbasic pointed out, your (updated) definition is the same as the definition AM give. "elements which are [each] invariant under all $g$"...